# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002) failed to connect, remote server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect to a remote server database using PHP code (mysqli)

```
$host = 'myIP:3306';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'pass';

$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass");

//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

I used myIP/phpmyadmin to make a database and i used putty to check if mysql was running correctly. I also checked the default port for mysql on my server, which was the default (3306).

The error given is described as either a connection fail/time-out/no response.

I also tried using PDO instead of mysqli but it gave me the same results. All other examples i could find where about localhosts and the solution given in those posts is using the socketpath to connect (which doesn't seem like a solution for me as it's remote..).

It's a linux server provided by school.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like some firewall in between blocks the requests.

Comment: If you're running Linux, you can add an exception to the firewall. In Ubuntu, this is `$ ufw allow 3306`.

Comment: try `telnet myIp 3306`. if that fails to connect as well, then you know there's a network issue. timed out = firewall silently dropping packets. connection refused = nothing listening on that ip:port, or firewall actively rejecting connections.

Comment: As far as i know my group hasn't done any configuration with firewalls, maybe it was done by a teacher before we received it but anyways. using the command $ ufw allow 3306 seemed work using putty. But the same error 2002 remains.

Comment: Does your MySQL user account allow remote connections?

Comment: Don't use `"$user"` when `$user` will do.

Comment: @Marc B using telnet i also get a timed-out error

Comment: @Gadget mind informing how/where i can check that?

Comment: then check your outgoing firewall, and the server's incoming firewall, and make sure that mysql traffic is allowed.

Comment: @Gijsys93 https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/

Answer (score -2):

With mysqli_connect(), you can use 6 parameters:

```
host, username, password, dbname, port, socket
```

Host and Port are separate.

Try using:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("myIP", "$user", "$pass", "dbname", "3306");
```

Also, the default port is 3306 so you probably do not even have to provide it.

Comment: Quotes around `$user` and `$pass` are useless.

Comment: @Jocelyn Correct, I just copied it from his code